# Tag filter list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created tag filter list based on some internet source. With 3 categories of presented filter (Composition, People, Theme) the user should be able to pick up one from any list and after the list should exclude the items that don't have the selected tag.

**HTML**

```
<h2>Composition</h2> 
<ul class="filter" id="composition">
    <li><a data-value="all">All</a> </li>
    <li><a data-value="landscape">Landscape</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="portait">Portait</a> </li>
    <li><a data-value="square">Square</a> </li>
</ul>

<h2>People</h2>
<ul class="filter" id="people">
    <li><a data-value="all">All</a> </li>
    <li><a data-value="people">People</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="nopeople">No People</a></li>
</ul>

<h2>Theme</h2>
<ul class="filter" id="theme">
    <li><a data-value="all">All</a> </li>
    <li><a data-value="Nature">Nature</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="Fashion">Fashion</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="Mountains">Mountains</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="Sea">Sea</a></li>    
</ul>

<h2>Data to filter</h2>
<ul> 
    <li class="item landscape people Nature">landscape people Nature</li> 
    <li class="item portait nopeople Fashion">portait nopeople Fashion</li> 
    <li class="item landscape people Mountains">landscape people Mountains</li> 
    <li class="item portait people Sea">portait people Sea</li> 
    <li class="item square people Mountains">square people Mountains</li> 
    <li class="item landscape people Fashion">landscape people Fashion</li> 
    <li class="item square nopeople Sea">square nopeople Sea</li> 
    <li class="item landscape nopeople Mountains">landscape nopeople Mountains</li> 
    <li class="item portait people Fashion">portait people Fashion</li> 
    <li class="item square nopeople Sea">square nopeople Sea</li> 
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("ul.filter li a").click(function() 
            { 
                $(this).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                var composition    = $('ul#composition li a.selected').data('value'); 
                var people    = $('ul#people li a.selected').data('value');
                var theme    = $('ul#theme li a.selected').data('value');
                var compositionSelector = ''; 
                var peopleSelector = '';  
                var themeSelector = '';        

                if (composition == "all" && people == "all" && theme == "all") 
                { 
                    //show all items 
                    $(".item").show(); 
                } 
                else 
                { 

                    if (theme != "all") 
                    { 
                        themeSelector = '.' + theme ;
                    } 

                    if (people != "all") 
                    { 
                        peopleSelector = '.' + people ;
                    } 

                    if (composition != "all") 
                    { 
                        compositionSelector = '.' + composition ;
                    } 


                    $(".item").hide(); 
                    $(compositionSelector + peopleSelector + themeSelector).show(); 
                } 

            }); 
        });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/22vh08ah/

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine at this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22vh08ah/1/), jQuery wasn't included and the console warning in yours is `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, caused by the library not being included in the document. No code was modified. Does your actual live project have jQuery included?

**EDIT:**
Now that you've clarified, try checking [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22vh08ah/3/). The problem is your class names are undefined unless a list item from each group is clicked. In order to fix this, you need to edit the markup itself to have the first, or "all" list item set as selected by default. This will prevent certain `if statements` from running every time, and setting your selectors as undefined.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. I assume the OP just didn't add jQuery to the Fiddle, and the issue is something related to the code, but OP has not told us what the issue is.

Comment: I am sorry, for not explaining what this filter should do. The idea is that with  3 categories of presented filter (Composition, People, Theme) the user should be able to pick up one from any list and after the list should exclude the items that don't have the selected tag.

Comment: @Bohdan Check my revised answer, it's working as you described for me now.

Comment: Rashad, I've checked and it works nice, thank you a lot for helping me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("ul.filter li a")
    .on('click', function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .closest('ul')
            .find('a')
            .removeClass('selected');
        $this
            .addClass('selected');
        var selector = [];
        $('ul li a.selected')
            .each(function() {
                var selectedValue = $(this).data('value');
                if (selectedValue !== 'all') {
                    selector.push(selectedValue);
                }
            });
        $(".item")
            .hide();
        $('.item'+ (selector.length ? '.' : '') + selector.join('.'))
            .show();
    });
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/22vh08ah/6/).